# Sometimes NSArrayController is not refreshing NSTableView after core data delete/update

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nstableview, nsarraycontroller

I am using `NSArrayController` Binding to populate `NSTableView` from core data. `NSArrayController` is connected to `mainQueueConcurrencyType` managed object context(main managed object).
parent of main managed object context is `privateQueueConcurrencyType` (background managed object context). Save call on main managed object context will push changes to background managed object context and save on background managed object context will save to persistent store.

`Prepares contents` and `Editable` are enabled in xib for `NSArrayController`

Core data table :
Path
Date
Status

I have unique constraints added to path.

Sometimes `NSArrayController` is not removing deleted object from arranged object after core data save.

```
  [context performBlock:^{
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"entity" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
        NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"path ==%@", path];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSArray *fetchedObjects = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
        SyncStatusEntry *syncStatus = [fetchedObjects firstObject];
        NSInteger status = syncStatus.status.integerValue;
        context deleteObject:syncStatus];
        [context save:nil];
        // Sometimes NSArrayController still have this object
   }];
```

Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: When you say "managed object" do you mean `NSManagedObjectContext`? Is the object removed from the main context?

Comment: @Willeke Yes, Updated question.

Comment: Is the object not removed from the main context? Or is the object removed from the main context and is it not removed from the array controller?

Comment: @Willeke Object removed from main context but not from array controller.

Comment: Currently I have added one quick fix, After deleting object from context, I am checking if object exist in arrayController.arrangedObjects, If exist I am removing it using [arrayController removeObject:entryToRemove].

Answer (score 1):

Apparently `NSArrayController` is notified when something changes in the context. This notification is sent in `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` which is automatically called if `automaticallyMergesChangesFromParent` is `YES`.